# Need help diagnosing: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Tags: php

I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

at this code:

```
<?php
    $uniqueFtypes = $ftypes = $converter->GetConvertedFileTypes();
    array_walk(
        $uniqueFtypes, 
        function(&$ftype, $key) {
            $ftype = $ftype['fileExt'];
        }
    );
    $uniqueFtypes = array_values(array_unique($uniqueFtypes));
    foreach ($uniqueFtypes as $key => $uftype)
    {
        echo $uftype;
        echo ($uftype != end($uniqueFtypes)) ? (($key != count($uniqueFtypes)-2) ? ', ' : ', or ') : '';
    }
?>
```

At this line:

```
array_walk(
    $uniqueFtypes, 
    function(&$ftype, $key) {
        $ftype = $ftype['fileExt'];
    }
);
```

PHP Version: 5.2.17

It works on localhost, I'm using latest UniServer. But when I moved this to my host, it gives that error.

Any help? :)

Edit: Here is others im not sure does it need fixing.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
ini_set('display_errors',0);

// Instantiate converter class
include 'VideoConverter.class.php';
$converter = new VideoConverter();

// On download of converted file
if (isset($_GET['output']))
{
    $converter->DownloadConvertedFile($_GET['output']);
}
```

Second

```
    $vidHosts = array_values($converter->GetVideoHosts());
    foreach ($vidHosts as $key => $host)
    {
        echo $host['name'];
        echo ($host != end($vidHosts)) ? (($key == count($vidHosts)-2) ? ((count($vidHosts) > 2) ? ', and ' : ' and ') : ', ') : '';
    }
```

Is there something that needs fixing on these 2 also?

Comment: Have you confirmed PHP version same on localhost and remote host?

Answer (score 6):

You can't use closures before php 5.3.  You need to change that `function` in the second argument of `array_walk` to `create_function`.  Try:

```
array_walk($uniqueFtypes, create_function('&$ftype, $key;',
   '$ftype = $ftype["fileExt"];'));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, after changing that line, it shows only white on my page so I think there is other code that needs to be fixed. I edited first post to show other codes that might need to be fixed, could you tell if its so?

Comment: @Lanibox it shouldn't only show white; turn errors on and tell me what they are so I can help you.  However, I think you should accept this and create a separate question if you have multiple, disparate issues.